# Unknown Curl error

Tags: php, curl

I got a small problem getting an unknown curl error from my script

> curl_error(): 180 is not a valid cURL handle resource

Here's the part which causes the error and
exact log: PHP Warning:  curl_error(): 180 is not a valid cURL handle resource on

```
if(curl_error($ch))  
{  
    curl_close($ch);  
    $resp = curl_error($ch); // That's the line causing the error  
    error_log(date('Y M D h:s:m '). ":  $current error:  "  .curl_error($ch)."\n", 3, '../../usererrors/'.$username.'errors');  
    return $resp;  
}
```

Comment: Hm i think that i might be for calling curl_error($ch); after curl_close($ch);
Going to do quick test :)

Answer (score 9):

I must admit that the error was caused by calling curl_close before curl_error.
So case closed hope someone got some help from this as well :)